# How to set up Magit Forge with Gitlab?

Tags: magit

Reading through Magits documentation there seems to be full support for github through Ghub.

I am having trouble replicating the set up for gitlab, it is a supported forge but does not have Ghub support.

Does anyone have a guide for set up?

Comment: (Caveat: This is from just a cursory glance.) It looks like `forge-github` requires `ghub` and `forge-gitlab` requires `glab` (which is part of the `ghub` ELPA package).  Perhaps you just need to be doing "glab" things instead of "ghub" things?

Comment: `glab.el` says "This library is implemented on top of Ghub.  Unlike Ghub, Glab does not support the guided creation of tokens because Gitlab lacks the features that would be necessary to implement that.  Users have to create tokens through the web interface."

Answer (score 2):

Forge is documented in the [Forge manual](https://magit.vc/manual/forge/), not in the Magit manual.

At [Supported Forges](https://magit.vc/manual/forge/Supported-Forges-and-Hosts.html) you can see that Gitlab is supported but that there are some limitations. One of these limitations is that you have to *manually* create and store a token, [as documented](https://magit.vc/manual/3.2.0/ghub/Manually-Creating-and-Storing-a-Token.html) in the Ghub manual.