# Setup Magit Forge to connect Gitlab

Tags: magit, forge, gitlab

I am using a Gitlab, say `gitlab.company.org`.  My username on that machine is `user` and I am using 2FA.

I have read the [Forge User and Developer Manual](https://magit.vc/manual/forge/index.html#SEC_Contents).  It asked to read and follow the instructions of the [GHub User and Developer Manual](https://magit.vc/manual/ghub/index.html#SEC_Contents), which I did.

I also read [How to set up Magit Forge with Gitlab?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55412/how-to-set-up-magit-forge-with-gitlab/57870#57870), but there is still no real solution/accepted answer, so it was not of much help to me.

The Ghub Manual states, that I have, first of all, to set up a global user name, which I did.

Next, I had to go to the Gitlab web site and create a personal token.  So I did, created a token, choose `write_repository` first, but added a second token later with `api` scope.

Next I copied the generated token(s) into my already existing `~/.authinfo` file, as was suggested in the Ghub Manual.  The entry meanwhile reads

```
machine gitlab.company.org/api/v4 login user^ghub password abcdef1234...
```

Now it was time to go back to the Forge Manual, Chapter 3 "Gettings Started" and to read its subsections.  Subsection 3.1 "Token Creation" hinted, that, for Gitlab, I need the `api` scope, so I dropped the initial token, created a new one, ...

I also copied the URL `https://gitlab.company.org/api/v4` into my web browser and it worked (kind of), by returning this string `{"error":"404 Not Found"}`.  As the [Gitlab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) offered some more URLs, I next tried `https://gitlab.company.org/api/v4/version`, which resulted in `{"version":"14.6.1","revision":"661d663ab2b"}`.  This convinces me, that the server is working correct and Emacsen should be able to get results.

BTW: The access tokens page shows, that the correct token was used to contact the server (`last_used 2 minutes ago`).  I feel I am on the right way.

On that stage I stoped, changed again into emacs and typed the following into the `*scratch*` buffer

```lisp
(setq auth-sources '("~/.authinfo"))
```

and run `eval-last-sexp`.  No errors.

Next I inserted something similar like this

```lisp
(ghub-request "GET" "/user" nil
              :forge 'gitlab
              :host "gitlab.company.org/api/v4"
              :username "user"
              :auth 'ghub)
```

and evaled it also.  This gave some noticeable errors, but showed, that emacs was reading from `~/.authinfo` file.  After some fiddling on that expression as well as the content on `~/.authinfo`, I got the contents listed above.  When I evaled that sexp, I get a result, but not in the desired form:

> if: HTTP Error: 403, "Forbidden", "/api/v4/user", ((error . "insufficient_scope") (error_description . "The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token.") (scope . "read_user api read_api"))  Interesting enough, the `last_used` counter doesn't change.

Thats how far I came.  But now I have no idea, what to try next.  AFAIK the `api` scope is the most powerful scope with no limitations.

Any hints, what to change?

Comment: I met with exactly the same issue.